# Supporting .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-client-profile

Are there any design considerations that need to be made when targeting the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile? I know it's a subset of the full framework, but what is missing and how will I know if my application will require the Client Profile or the full framework? Has anyone successfully developed an application using the Client Profile that can share their thoughts about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Client Profile is mainly missing server-side things, i.e. ASP.NET and the like. You can just develop for client profile and let the compiler handle the rest (you'll get warnings if you use something that is not available on client profile). And if you can't do anything about it, switching to the full framework is just a click on a check box.

Answer (score -3):

You only need [.NET Framwork 3.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.net_framework) features if you consider using LINQ and ADO.NET Entity Framework or the new System.Addin namespace.

[image: .NET Framework Stack]

When creating a new project in Visual Studio 2008 you can select the target framework. This will automatically show or hide the namespaces which are not available to the selected version.

Comment: Where would the SP1 Client Profile fit into that model? I know I want to target the 3.5 framework, I'm just not sure if I can get away with targeting only the Client Profile.

Comment: As far as i know Service Pack 1 does not change this model, it only contains some bugfixes and performance improvements of the initial release.
In my point of view you don't have to worry if SP1 is installed or not. The interface to the framework functions won't change.

Comment: I think the question is about the Client Profile, rather than SP1 or .NET 3.5.